# sendVendorSpecificResultCode What does it do? Bluetooth Headset

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I was just looking at: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothHeadset.html

I am curious if anyone knows exactly what sendVendorSpecificResultCode does.

Lets say I have two android devices and I want one android device to send a Volume Up or Volume down to the other device. Do you think that would work?

Thanks!